# data.table's tables() function runs some of my .Rprofile functions

Tags: r, data.table

In my .Rprofile I have the following two lines defined in my `.First`

```
makeActiveBinding(".refresh", function() { system("R"); q("no") }, .GlobalEnv)
makeActiveBinding('.rm', function() {rm(list=ls(envir = .GlobalEnv),envir=.GlobalEnv); gc()}, .GlobalEnv)
```

They're usually harmless, unless I type them by accident!  The first makes a `.refresh` function that will quit and restart the R session.  The second empties the global environment.  However, when using the `tables()` function from `data.table` these two functions are run which isn't exactly desirable.

For the moment, I've removed them from my `.First` but I'm curious if there is a way to avoid this.  The offending lines in the `tables()` function are:

```
tt = objects(envir = env, all.names = TRUE)
ss = which(as.logical(sapply(tt, function(x) is.data.table(get(x, 
    envir = env)))))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just discovered a downside to using active bindings in that way. Why don't you instead create ordinary functions `.rm` and `.refresh`, that you call in the usual way (i.e. `.rm()` and `.refresh()`), and which won't be executed upon simple inspection?

Here's what part of your `.First` might then look like:

```
.First <- function() {
    assign(".rm", 
           function() {rm(list=ls(envir=.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv)}, 
           pos = .GlobalEnv)
}

## Try it out
j <- 1:10
ls()
.First()
.rm()
ls()
```

---

**Edit, with solution:**

On further thought, this seems to work, only executing the core bits when `.rm` is 'called' directly. It works by inspecting the length of the call stack, and only running `rm(...)` if there is just one call in it (representing the current call to `.rm()`. If `.rm` is called/touched by a call to some *other* function (e.g. `tables()`), the call stack will be longer, and `rm()` won't be executed.:

```
makeActiveBinding('.rm', 
                 function() {
                     if(length(sys.calls())==1) {
                         rm(list=ls(envir = .GlobalEnv),envir=.GlobalEnv); gc()
                      }
                 },   
                 .GlobalEnv)

## Try _it_ out
library(data.table)

j <- 100
.rm
ls()

j <- 100
tables()
ls()
```

Comment: That is how I wrote them initially, but my fingers got so tired from typing `()` that I decided to play with fire...

Comment: Fair enough. If you try to keep that fire going, though, over time it'll end up costing you more than a few keystrokes ;)

Comment: Isn't there some way to check the current environment, or a parameter that says "this is an interactive environment..." , and make your functions use that info to decide whether or not to execute?

Comment: There is an `interactive` function returning a logical value that is often used to check whether an instance of R is such.

Comment: I think its best to put the fire out while I still can.  I was mostly curious about semantics and any thoughts on this.  But @JoshO'Brien is right and I'll just make them real functions.

Comment: @Justin And just like that, I'll light the fire right back up (see the code just added above)! Not sure this will make the active binding 'safe' in all cases, but it does work in the case you put forward.

Comment: Well aint that clever!  I think I'm still sold on moving past my old ways of dumping R sessions that often and writing better code...